# Google Sheets Iterative Calculation

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I am hung up on this iterative calculation in GS. I need an array formula to give me a basic `TRUE` or `FALSE` response based upon the result in the cell immediately above. I've created a sandbox chart here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YzC5mbxv4jDGnBn8HJ62ehBxMx1UGlNJczVVCm3Vjh4

[image: Screenshot of Google Sheets Sample]

Column A includes a checkbox next to each Category. Column B is a list of Category Names and each sub-entry. We're going to constantly add new sub-entries over time. When a user checks the box next to the Category, I want the Category name and all sub-entries to be labeled TRUE (as shown in column D). I have dragged this formula down in Column D, however, this is not a sustainable solution as our table will eventually contain about 6,500 categories each with 10-30 sub-entries. We need an array formula solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(A2:A) <= MAX(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(B2:B)), ROW(A2:A))),
 VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A), FILTER({ROW(A2:A), A2:A}, LEN(A2:A)), 2), ))
```

[image: 0]